# ASM access violation when writing to [ADDR]

Tags: assembly

I trying change a character from char array with asm but ollydbg give me these error

Can i bypass access violation ?

**[Image]**

[image]

Comment: A guess is that the parameter isn't a char array (`char arr[10]`), but a string literal (`"Hello World!"`). Literals in C or C++ cannot be modified.

Comment: on assembly level they can, once you will call some OS API to remap your code segment as writeable memory, but it's not something you would want to do voluntarily (especially in case of your knowledge level), in ordinary application code just define the string in writeable area, like Bo suggested.

Comment: You are right, is literal string, i was trying change it but appears imposible, i will try with an array char somearray[]

Comment: Ped7g you are a pedant